# Save class name from sklearn.metrics.classification_report

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have the following classification report:

```py
                precision    recall  f1-score   support

      B-Origin       0.99      0.98      0.98       787
     B-Opinion       0.90      0.85      0.88        41
I-Relationship       0.95      0.80      0.87       153
        I-Year       0.93      0.97      0.95       285
      I-Origin       0.94      0.90      0.92       570
```

How can I save the class names as strings in a list?

```py
names = ["B-Origin", "B-Opinion", "I-Relationship", "I-Year", "I-Origin"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
report = classification_report(y_true, y_pred, output_dict=True)
dfReport = pandas.DataFrame(report).transpose()
myList = dfReport.index.tolist()
```